# loop not iterating in c

Tags: c, loops, matrix-inverse

I have recently started coding and was trying to write a program to find the inverse of a matrix using Gauss Jordan method. I try to transform the given matrix to an identity matrix by using ro transformations and apply the same to corresponding elements of identity matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    float a[5][5],b[5][5]={};
    int n,i,j,k,m,o,p,q;
    printf("Enter order n of square matrix : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter %d elements : ",n*n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%f",&a[i][j]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%10f",a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(n>=3)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            b[i][i]=1;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
                if(a[i][i]==0)
                    for(m=i+1;m<n;m++)
                        if(a[m][i]!=0)
                        {
                            for(o=0;o<n;o++)
                            {
                                a[m][o]+=a[m][o]+a[i][o];
                                a[i][o]=a[m][o]-a[i][o];
                                a[m][o]=a[m][o]-a[i][o];
                                b[m][o]+=b[m][o]+b[i][o];
                                b[i][o]=b[m][o]-b[i][o];
                                b[m][o]=b[m][o]-b[i][o];
                            }
                            break;
                        }
            for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                {if(a[j][i]!=0)
                {
                    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                    {
                        b[j][k]=b[j][k]*a[i][i]-a[j][i]*b[i][k];
                        a[j][k]=a[j][k]*a[i][i]-a[j][i]*a[i][k];
                    }
                }
                for(p=0;p<n;p++)
                {
                    for(q=0;q<n;q++)
                        printf("%10f",a[p][q]);
                    printf("\t\t");
                    for(q=0;q<n;q++)
                        printf("%10f",b[p][q]);
                    printf("\n");
                }}
        }
            for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
                for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
                    if(a[j][i]!=0)
                    {
                        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                        {
                            b[j][k]=b[j][k]*a[i][i]-a[j][i]*b[i][k];
                            a[j][k]=a[j][k]*a[i][i]-a[j][i]*a[i][k];
                        }
                    }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                b[i][j]=(b[i][j])/(a[i][i]);
        printf("\n\n\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        printf("%10f",b[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

It is not giving the required output(correct inverse) and so i tried to print the two matrices after each row transformation(for the beginning part). Then i found that one of the loops was not iterating(the k variableloop) and loop was only running for k=0.I can't seem to find what is wrong.
the input which i was using was 3 , 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8

Comment: Scale back your program, preferably to an empty `main` function. Then add one ***small*** bit of code at a time, build with extra warnings enabled and treat them as errors, and test. Only when the code builds cleanly and passes all tests you continue with the next ***small*** bit of code. If you do that, then it's much easier to catch errors, where they might come from, and to *debug* your program.

Comment: If the k loop only runs for 0, then `n` must be 0. Do you know its value in case of your problem. What else did you check during debuggin. Otherwise, as in comment before https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: @Yunnosch  I am using the scanf statement for n value. In the input I am giving n value is 3.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your suggestion. After analysing only that part of code i noticed that a[j][i] the variable whose product i wanted to subtract was becoming zero and i needed to change that.